# Enable UIBarButtonItem if multiple UITextFields are all populated

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitextfield, uibarbuttonitem

I have 3 UITextFields in a grouped UITableView and am trying to figure out the correct logic to only have my 'Save' UIBarButtonItem enabled when none of the UITextFields are empty.

I'm currently using the `- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string` UITextField delegate method to detect changes to the field character by character, but it is providing inconsistent results.

Any ideas?

Edit: Here is the code I'm now using. As you can see I've placed my text fields into an array so I can iterate through them. As it is now, the save button doesn't enable until I enter the 2nd character in the 3rd field. Also it alternates enabled/disabled as a remove characters one by one from the fields.

```
NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

    BOOL allValid;

    if (newString.length)
    {
        // Cycle through array checking for completeness
        for (int i = 0; i < [textFieldArray count]; i++)
        {
            if ([[[textFieldArray objectAtIndex:i] text] length] > 0)
            {
                allValid = YES;
                NSLog(@"TextField #%i Validates.", i);
            }
            else
            {
                allValid = NO;
                NSLog(@"TextField #%i Does Not Validate.", i);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Invalid");
        allValid = NO;
    }

    if (allValid)
        [saveButton setEnabled:YES];
    else
        [saveButton setEnabled:NO];

    return YES;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here's how I finally did it.

I created `- (IBAction)validateFields:(id)sender` and connected it to the Editing Changed outlet on UITextField. It looks like this.

```
- (IBAction)validateFields:(id)sender
{
    BOOL valid = YES;

    // On every press we're going to run through all the fields and get their length values. If any of them equal nil we will set our bool to NO.
    for (int i = 0; i < [textFieldArray count]; i++)
    {
        if (![[[textFieldArray objectAtIndex:i] text] length])
            valid = NO;
    }

    [saveButton setEnabled:valid];
}
```

I've given it a pretty decent go and couldn't get the save button to enable on any combination of empty text fields so I'm going to say this is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

How exactly are you using the method?  Here's how I would do it:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
  NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
  if (newString.length) {
    //If all the others are also non-empty, enable your button
  }
  return YES;
}
```

But it might make more sense for you to enable your button after the user presses the enter key, which is easier to deal with.  Just use a didEndEditingOnExit or didEndEditing event on the text fields and check there to see if they're non-empty.